# Binding not firing observer in newer versions of Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I recently updated from Ember.js 0.9.8.1 to Ember.js 1.0-pre2. Now I find that observers are not fired when I set bindings.

Here is a small example illustrating the problem:

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view App.SimpleView textBinding="App.text"}}
</script>​
```

Code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.text = "new";

App.SimpleView = Ember.View.extend({
    text: 'old',
    fired: 'no',
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Text: {{view.text}}. Observer fired: {{view.fired}}'),

    textObserver: function() {
        this.set('fired', 'yes');
    }.observes('text')
});
```

With Ember.js 0.9.8.1 it works as expected, printing *Text: new. Observer fired: yes*​, ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBDnu/)) however in 1.0-pre2, the observer is not fired ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSyug/)).

This small like a bug to me, but before reporting it, I would like to ask if something in the API changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after discussion with Kristofor Selden, the behavior in 0.9.8.1 was a bug.
In 1.0.pre-2, in your fiddle, when the view is instantiated, App.text is already set to "new", this is an expected behavior that the observer is not fired.